# Redirect input to .NET Core Console App on debugging in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, .net-core, console-application

In a C# .NET Core Console App, how I can define a redirect input to app on debugging?

I've tried with "Application arguments" of project properties, but not work.

[image]

The application open and immediately closes.

In VSCode it is possible with `args` config of `launch.json` file:
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_redirect-inputoutput-tofrom-the-debug-target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done in the same way. A `Properties/launchSettings.json` file should be generated, similar to this one:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "YourProjectName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "< input-file.txt"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Please note that, if you're debugging from Visual Studio, you need to make sure your input file is copied to the output folder so that the redirection works.

i.e. you can manually add this to the `.csproj`:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="input-file.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

or, as @paulsm4 suggested, configure it via VS interface: `input-file.txt` -> `Properties` -> 'Copy'

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Minor addition: I believe you can also set "input-file.txt" > Properties to "Copy" in the MSVS UI (vs. manually hacking the .csproj).